# Parcelable Interface

Tags: android, parcelable

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyPacelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>()
```

I took the code above from a website. It says we have to create a `CREATOR` constant to make the Parcelable work. But I thought Parcelable is an interface, and we cannot create an object out of an interface. So I am confused about the code, as it looks like a constructor to create an object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the code you cite is incomplete. CREATOR is required to allow the framework to create your object when deserializing, note that it is a generic interface, and the type parameter you provided is 'MyParcelable', so its 'createFromParcel' method has the return type of 'MyParcelable'. so you can create a 'MyParcelable' instance in it. like this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyPacelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
    public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyParcelable(in);
    }

    public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyParcelable[size];
    }
};
```